# MongoDB validation failed from has_and_belongs_to_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am building a simple script to populate a MongoDB database. This is my first time using a NoSQL DB and I feel I may be thinking about this problem from a SQL DB standpoint.

The basis of this script is to populate a database that holds a few collections that relate to one another. But when I run my script, I see an invalid errors when building/saving the documents.

I have three collections; `Book`, `Author`, and `Style`, with the following relationships.

- A `Book` has many `Authors`
- An `Author` has many `Books`
- An `Author` has many `Styles`
- A `Style` has many `Authors`

The models are defined as followed:

```rb
# Book Model
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :title, type: String

  validates :title, presence: true

  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors

  index({ title: 'text' })
end
```

```rb
# Author Model
class Author
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, type: String

  validates :name, presence: true

  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
  has_and_belongs_to_many :styles

  index({ name: 1 }, { unique: true })
end
```

```rb
# Style Model
class Style
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :type, type: String

  validates :type, presence: true

  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors

  index({ type: 1 }, { unique: true, name: "type_index" })
end
```

And then this is my script:

```rb
# script.rb
book = Book.new
book.title = "Good Omens"

['Neil Gaiman', 'Terry Pratchett'].each do |author_name|
  author = Author.find_by(name: author_name)
  if author.nil?
    author = Author.new(name: author_name)
  end

  # a list of writing styles this author can have
  # pretend that there's a list of styles per author
  literary_styles.each do |style_name|
    style = Style.find_by(type: style_name)

    if style.nil?
      author.styles.build(Style.new(type: style_name))
    else
      unless author.styles.include? style.id
        author.styles << style
      end
    end
  end

  author.valid? #=> false 
  author.errors #=>  @messages={:styles=>["is invalid"]}
  book.author.build(book.attributes)
  book.save
end
```

The `Book` document is created, but the `Author` and `Style` do not persist due to the invalid Style validation error. I wish I could see exactly what is causing the validations to fail, but the messaging is very vague. I suspect it is coming from some built in validation from the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation between `Author` and `Style` but I can't put my finger on it.

What I find interesting is that the `Book` document has an `author_ids` property which is populated with id's but when I jump into the console, there are no authors that can be pulled up or tied to the `Book`.

Happy to give more info if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd need to know a bit more to definitively tell you what the issue is -- What version of Mongoid are you using? Are you running this script on an empty database, or do the Author and Style documents already exist? What do those look like?

That being said, I do see a couple of bugs in your script, though I'm not sure if they're causing your problem:

1. ```
   if style.nil?
         author.styles.build(Style.new(type: style_name))
   else
         ...
   ```

I believe the line inside the if statement will throw an error. Instead, it should say `author.styles.build(type: style_name)`.

2. ```
   unless author.styles.include? style.id
       author.styles << style
   end
   ```

The expression after `unless` is always going to evaluate to false because `author.styles` is an array of `Style` objects, not style ids. Instead, it should probably say `author.style_ids.include? style.id` or `author.styles.include? style`

Let me know if that helps! I'm happy to debug some more if you provide me with the extra info I requested.